# Cannot set JSTL User variable instead of java.lang.String

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

So I have a code listed below, I want to set ${tempUser} from session scope or ${userToEdit} from request scope if exists to new variable so I'm not gonna need to duplicate my code and gonna use ${userBean.login} etc.
The problem is userBean is still the string and it throws the exception (no login property). How can I create variable of User type here?

```
    <c:set var="userBean" scope="page">${tempUser}</c:set>

    <c:if test="${not empty userToEdit}">
        <c:set var="userBean">${userToEdit}</c:set>
    </c:if>

    <div class="section no-pad-bot" id="index-banner">
        <div class="container">
            <h2 class="header center orange-text">
                <c:choose>
                    <c:when test="${not empty userToEdit}">
                        Edit user
                    </c:when>
                    <c:otherwise>
                        Add user
                    </c:otherwise>
                </c:choose>
                <c:out value="${userBean}"/>
                ${userBean.login}
            </h2>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<c:set var="userBean" scope="page" value="${tempUser}" />
<c:if test="${not empty userToEdit}">
    <c:set var="userBean" value="${userToEdit}" />
</c:if>
```

Or simply

```
<c:set var="userBean" value="${(empty userToEdit) ? tempUser : userToEdit}" />
```

Comment: Oh well, I thought I tried it before.
Thanks, that actually works now.